# How a user could change the starting Activity of an application?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

How a user (unregistered not logged-in) can change the starting Activity of an application?

I need code:

1. When you first run the application on the device output Activity to select countries (not localization - the difference in the content).
2. When selecting the settings are saved, and when you run the Activity will run the selected country.
3. Ability to change the settings in the displayed Activity.

It is even possible?

It is necessary that the user selects to himself one of the 2-3 Activity, which differ only content.

Answer (score 4):

I would make a setting that stores like an `int` or `enum`. You would store that in `SharedPreferences`.

You'll have a `MainActivity` entry point, that in `onCreate()` immediately reads that setting and redirects to the right `Activity`.

**Pseudo-code:**

SettingsActivity:

Option: Activity1/Activity2/Activity3:

```
SharedPreferences.edit().putInt("entryPoint", 2).apply();
```

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

MainActivity:

```
@Override
void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    switch (SharedPreferences.getInt("entryPoint", default)) {
        case 1:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
            break ;
        case 2:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
            break ;
        case 3:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
            break ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand the SharedPreferences=( please help me... need codes to much

Comment: @Дима if you don't understand it then you should [read about it](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) before asking for code. If you still don't understand after making an attempt, then you should post a new question showing your attempt and explaining what you don't understand.